# r Nomad categorical optimisation (snomadr)

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use the Nomad technique for blackbox optimisation from the crs package (C implementation), which is called via the snomadr function. The method works when trying straight numerical optimisation, but errors when categorical features are included. However the help for categorical optimisation is not very well documented, so I am struggling to see where I am going wrong. Reproducible code below:

```
library(crs)
library(randomForest)
```

Illustrating this on randomForest & the iris dataset.

Creating the randomForest model (leaving the last row out as starting points for the optimizer)

```
rfIris <- randomForest(x=iris[-150,-c(1)], y=unlist(iris[-150,1]))
```

The objective function (functions we want to optimize)

```
objFn <- function(x0,model){

  preds <- predict(object = model, newdata = x0)
  as.numeric(preds)
}
```

Test to see if the objective function works (should return ~6.37)

```
objOut <- objFn(x0=unlist(iris[150,-c(1)]),model = rfIris)
```

Creating initial conditions, options list, and upper/lower bounds for Nomad

```
x0 <- iris[150,-c(1)]
x0 <- unlist(x0)

options <- list("MAX_BB_EVAL"=10000,
            "MIN_MESH_SIZE"=0.001,
            "INITIAL_MESH_SIZE"=1,
            "MIN_POLL_SIZE"=0.001,
            "NEIGHBORS_EXE" = c(1,2,3),
            "EXTENDED_POLL_ENABLED" = 'yes', 
            "EXTENDED_POLL_TRIGGER" = 'r0.01',
            "VNS_SEARCH" = '1')

up <- c(10,10,10,10)
low <- c(0,0,0,0)
```

Calling the optimizer

```
opt <- snomadr(eval.f = objFn, n = 4, bbin = c(0,0,0,2), bbout = 0, x0= x0 ,model = rfIris, opts=options,
               ub = up, lb = low)
```

and I get an error about the **NEIGHBORS_EXE** parameter in the options list. It seems as if I need to supply NEIGHBORS_EXE a file corresponding to a set of 'extended poll' coordinates, however is it not clear what these exactly are.

The method works by setting "EXTENDED_POLL_ENABLED" = 'no' in the options list, as it then ignores the categorical variables and defaults to numerical optimisation, but this is not what I want.

I also managed to pull up some additional information for NEIGHBORS_EXE using

```
snomadr(information=list("help"="-h NEIGHBORS_EXE"))
```

and again, do not understand what the 'neighbours.exe' is meant to be.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the response from Zhenghua who coded the R interface:

> The issue is that he did not configure the parameter “NEIGHBORS_EXE” properly. He need to prepare an Executable file for defining the neighbors, put the executable file in the folder where R is called, and then set the parameter “NEIGHBORS_EXE” to the executable file name.

You can contact us at nomad@gerad.ca if you wish to continue the discussion.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  While this seems tangentially helpful, answers should be public and self-contained; I suggest this should be recast as a comment.

Comment: @tripleee this isn't comment material; it's not suggesting improvement or requesting clarification. it's answering the question or solving the problem; that's a space for answers.

Comment: Do any of you have an example file of what NEIGHBORS_EXE should contain for the Iris example above?

Answer (score -1):

About the neighbours_exe parameter you can refer to the section 7.1 of user guide of Nomad
https://www.gerad.ca/nomad/Downloads/user_guide.pdf

Comment: Hi @Christophe, I have read section 7.1 and have gone through your C++ as well as Python code, and figured out that neighbours_exe requires a script that creates the neighbourhood coordinates for the categorical features. However what I am struggling to do is successfully get it working in R (using snomanr), as feeding the parameter with a anything seems to just throw an error, like with the example I have above.